# PHP while function with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to change this line: `while (($number = fgetcsv($handle, 32768, ',')) !== FALSE)` to check in if the user has limit to perform the task.

I want to add something like this `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = $username AND queryused < limit` if it gets a result, the `while`funcions continues if not, it stops.

Comment: use some variable before the while as the condition, then asign the query result to that variable at the end of each iteration of the while, i'm not sure if i understood right

Comment: @arieljuod thats what I want, but I'm no expert, can you help ?

Comment: how do you run the query? what's queryused and what's limit? any code?

Comment: queryused = everytime the while functions do its loop, it add one to queryused, so its like queryused+1, limit its how many times the while funcion can work, if queryused its higher than limit, it wont work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Like @arieljuod suggested, you could do something like this.

```
$count = 0;
while ($count < YOUR_LIMIT && $number = fgetcsv($handle, 32768, ',')){
    //do query
    $count++;
}
```

This way, each time you iterate, the loop will perform the function only if $number has been set to a value AND each previous query has been successful. If a query fails, no other iteration will pass the criteria.

NOTE: you are ASSIGNING the $variable number in the while condition. If it receives a "truthy" value (i.e. not 0, empty, etc.) then it will be recognized as "truthful" even though it is not a boolean per se.

Comment: sure but the count and limit should be loaded from the DB everytime it loops

Comment: Seems like a heavy loop... but you can do that in a separate query, store the values, and use them in your other query if you really need that.

Answer (score 0):

you should only load "limit" and "queryused" once before the loop, do the loop and then update the value of queryused, something like

```
$used = query_to_get_queryused_from_db;
$limit = query_to_get_limit_from_db;
$count = 0;
while($count+$used < $limit && $number = fgetcsv($handle, 32768, ',')){
  //something
  $count++;
}
query_to_update_queryused_on_db //using $count+$used
```

doing one query on each iteration is reaaaaaally bad, always try to aviod queries inside loops, do them only if there's no other way to do that